# How to create custom Locator Styles in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Does anyone know if there is any public documentation on how to create these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this ESRI technical paper
"Customizing ArcGIS 10 locators" 
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aeb00de638f3492a93308a4a03183c7d

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Please don't be discouraged if this reply doesn't get much attention: the thread is old and has many answers already.  Take a stab at answering some of the newer questions and see what kind of results that gets :-).

Comment: This looks more along the lines of what I'm after. Thanks Seb!

Comment: The link has gone dead.

Comment: Post edited with updated link, I wish ESRI would forward documentation links when they update their website.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own composite address locators.

(Might be easier to modify an existing one to start with)

[http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_composite_address_locator/00250000003r000000](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_composite_address_locator/00250000003r000000/)/

The maximum number of participating address locators in a composite locator is 30, but it is recommended not to use more than 10, otherwise geocoding may be significantly slower.

Commonly used address locator styles
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00250000000v000000.htm

Useful source:

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geocoding-Gallery/details?entryID=12D8D400-1422-2418-34B0-4FE1CC06C0ED

9.3.1 but can be used with ArcGIS 10

*"They can be used to create locators with ArcGIS 10. The locators can then be used for geocoding at ArcGIS 9.3x or 10."*

Migration tips:

Migrating address locators created with ArcGIS prior to version 10
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Migrating_address_locators_created_with_ArcGIS_prior_to_version_10/00250000001w000000/

Comment: esri docs:  useful when you know where to look.

Comment: indeed, though you need to have knowledge of the right 'terminology' to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not really what I'm after. The question is about Locator Styles. When installing ArcGIS Desktop 10 there is a directory called Locators that contains (for example) USAddress.lot.xml which defines the parser rules for a string. What I'd like to do is create one of these.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to look into the **Geocoding Development Kit**.

Even though [this KB article](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=27228) was last updated June 2010, there is no mention of it being used with ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: thanks Kirk. I've have used that toolkit in the past. What I'd really like is the toolkit or docos for 10.

Comment: @Jonathan any success on locator styles creation you could share ?. Thanks